# Configure socket.io with htpps under Node.js with express and session

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https, socket.io

I passed few days ago my NodeJs app under https (thanks to [let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) )

Problem is now socket.io won't connect anymore to my server. 
Here it's my front-end code (under React):

**layout.jsx**

```
socketHost: 'https://localhost:9091',
...
this.socket = io(this.socketHost, {secure: true});
...
this.socket.on('update', function(data){ ...
```

Before the https socket.io was working just fine (I mean the code structure is ok.)
Here it's my serverSide code:

**index.js:**

```
var app =  express();
app
.use(Session)
.use((req, res, next)=>{
    if(req.secure)
        next();
    else
        res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
})
...
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
httpServer.listen(conf.mainPort);
httpsServer.listen(conf.httpsPort);

require('./app/socket')(httpsServer, Session, store);
```

**app/socket.js:**

```
...
io  = require('socket.io')(conf.socketPort),
ios = require('socket.io-express-session');
...
module.exports = function(app, session){

    var module = {};

    if(app && session){
        io.use(ios(session));
        io.on('connection', function(socket){
        ....
```

I'm not using `store` param becaused it's useless for me at this point.

And now the error in the browser:

```
GET https://localhost:9091/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1454751433013-95 
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION FOUNDED**

While trying to write a good resume of my problem, I just founded the solution, and the problem.
I just needed to pass the httpsServer into my socket and forget about the port:

**app/socket.js:**

```
 io          = require('socket.io'),
 ios         = require('socket.io-express-session');

var sockets  = {};

module.exports = function(app, session){

    var module = {};
    if(app && session){
        io = io(app);
        io.use(ios(session));
    ...

    return module;
};
```

And on the front side do not map any port:

**layout.jsx**

```
    //useless: socketHost: 'https://localhost',

    this.socket = io({secure: true});
```

So I don't have any question actually.. but I let this here if someone get stuck on the same kind of trouble.

Have a good day!